# How to distinguish cut event and copy event when using only function with devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am starting to learn BarManager class from `Devexpress.com`. But when I read this code:

```
> using DevExpress.XtraBars;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BarManager barManager = new BarManager();
    barManager.Form = this;
    // Prevent excessive updates while adding and customizing bars and bar items. 
    // The BeginUpdate must match the EndUpdate method. 
    barManager.BeginUpdate();
    // Create two bars and dock them to the top of the form. 
    // Bar1 - is a main menu, which is stretched to match the form's width. 
    // Bar2 - is a regular bar. 
    Bar bar1 = new Bar(barManager, "My MainMenu");
    Bar bar2 = new Bar(barManager, "My Bar");
    bar1.DockStyle = BarDockStyle.Top;
    bar2.DockStyle = BarDockStyle.Top;
    // Position the bar1 above the bar2 
    bar1.DockRow = 0;
    // The bar1 must act as the main menu. 
    barManager.MainMenu = bar1;

    // Create bar items for the bar1 and bar2 
    BarSubItem subMenuFile = new BarSubItem(barManager, "File");
    BarSubItem subMenuEdit = new BarSubItem(barManager, "Edit");
    BarSubItem subMenuView = new BarSubItem(barManager, "View");

    BarButtonItem buttonOpen = new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Open");
    BarButtonItem buttonExit = new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Exit");
    BarButtonItem buttonCopy = new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Copy");
    BarButtonItem buttonCut = new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Cut");
    BarButtonItem buttonViewOutput = new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Output");

    subMenuFile.AddItems(new BarItem[] { buttonOpen, buttonExit});
    subMenuEdit.AddItems(new BarItem[] { buttonCopy, buttonCut});
    subMenuView.AddItem(buttonViewOutput);

    //Add the sub-menus to the bar1 
    bar1.AddItems(new BarItem[] {subMenuFile, subMenuEdit, subMenuView });

    // Add the buttonViewOutput to the bar2. 
    bar2.AddItem(buttonViewOutput);

    // A handler to process clicks on bar items 
    barManager.ItemClick += new ItemClickEventHandler(barManager_ItemClick);     

    barManager.EndUpdate();
}

void barManager_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    BarSubItem subMenu = e.Item as BarSubItem;
    if (subMenu != null) return;
    MessageBox.Show("Item '" + e.Item.Caption + "' has been clicked");
}
```

Everything is OK, it is simply displayed caption of button. But in fact, when user click cut button -> action cut will do (click `copy button` => action copy will do). But cut event and copy event all use same function `barManager_ItemClick()`. So How to distinguish cut event and copy event when using only this function?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than handling the BarManager's ItemClick event, you can assign an individual [ItemClick event event handler](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem.ItemClick.event) to each bar item. This makes it easier to distinguish which BarButtonItem initiated the click.

If you don't want to do this, you will need to test if the e.Item parameter in the BarManager's ItemClick handler to determine which BarButtonItem fired the click.